# What is the $\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(\arccos (x))^{1-x}$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to 1^{-}}(\arccos (x))^{1-x}$$
I've tried L'Hopetal rule, but derivative contains $$ln(arccos(x))$$ and it isn't defined in $x=1$. And because of that I couldn't use Taylor series

Comment: What are you thoughts?

Comment: I tried to L'Hopital it, but derivative contains ln(arccosx) which is not defined in x=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put $x=\cos(t)$.

when $x$ goes to $1^-, t $ goes to $0^+$.

thus

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}(\arccos(\cos(t)))^{1-\cos(t)}$$

$$=\lim_{t\to 0^+}e^{(1-\cos(t))\ln(t)  }$$

$$\lim_{t\to 0^+}e^{ \frac{1-\cos(t) }{t^2}t^2\ln(t)}=e^0=1.$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that by letting $t=\arccos(x)$,
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 1^-}{(\arccos x)^{1-x}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}{t^{1-\cos(t)}}=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\exp((1-\cos(t))\ln(t))\\=
\lim_{t\rightarrow 0^+}\exp\left(\frac{t^2}{2}\ln(t)\right)=e^0=1.$$

Comment: Why does ln(t) decrease slower than t^2?

Comment: Note that $\lim_{t\to 0^+}t\ln(t)=\lim_{s\to +\infty }1/s\ln(1/s)=\lim_{s\to +\infty }-\ln(s)/s=0$ because $s$ goes faster to infinity than $\ln(s)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! I got it

Comment: @Dukalis Well done! BTW the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted" ;-). http://math.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: Oh please, little children @Salah and RobertZ, if the op wants to accept an answer, they will. Stop begging the asker for points (accepts, votes or whatever).  I'm writing this comment in part to draw attention to the pandering for rep you both display.

Comment: In case you try to delete your comment which displays your pandering for rep, Robert Z, I'll quote your comment here: **"BTW the person who asked can mark one answer as "accepted" ;-)"**

Comment: @amWhy I am sorry that you are disappointed. I am just quoting what is written here: http://math.stackexchange.com/tour
Anyway, you are right, this action is deplorable. I will not ever leave a comment like that. I want to be a little GOOD child.

Answer (score 0):

> In [THIS ANSWER](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1753645/evaluation-of-limit-at-infinity), I showed that the arccosine function satisfies the inequalities
>
> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\sqrt{1-t^2}\le \arccos(t)\le \frac{\sqrt{1-t^2}}{t} }\tag 1$$
>
> for $0<t<1$.

---

Using $(1)$, we can write for $x\in (0,1)$

$$\left(1-x^2\,\right)^{(1-x)/2}\le (\arccos(x))^{1-x}\le \left(\frac{1-x^2}{x^2}\,\right)^{(1-x)/2} \tag 2$$

Recalling that $\lim_{x\to 1^-}(1-x)^{1-x}=\lim_{t\to 0^+}t^t=1$, and applying  the squeeze theorem to $(2)$ yields that coveted limit

> $$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #C0A000]{\lim_{x\to 1^-}(\arccos(x))^{1-x}=1}$$